# Multi Sites in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, multisite

I'm trying to add another site to the same domain within Sitecore.

So my new site would be accesiable via `www.example.com/au`

My Sitecore structure is:

```
Content
   Main Site
     Home
   Sub Site (subsite)
     Home
```

I have the following in my config

```
<site name="SubSite" patch:after="site[@name='website']"  virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/au" rootpath="/sitecore/content/subsite" startItem="/home" database="master" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="50MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="25MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="10MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" cacheRenderingParameters="true" renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB">
```

But when I navigate to `www.example.com/au` it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

[image: error]

Comment: Try `patch:before` instead of `patch:after`. I think website site takes all the request before they hit your site. And maybe you'll need virtual folder set to `au` as well

Comment: @MarekMusielak: You should put this in as an answer! I was going to answer this question with pretty much the same thing, but happened to notice your comment

Comment: I'm still having issues when I make the changes see attached screenshot above @Jay S

Comment: I think it may be because you're trying to use virtual/physical folder name same as a language and Sitecore confuses one with another. Can you try using "aus" instead?